# Can't start apache2 on debian

Tags: server, debian, apache2

Please see my error screenshot and advice me what should i do

[image]

Comment: how is that related to PHP?

Comment: This is more of a devops question. Try and ask over at [Super user](https://superuser.com/) or [Server fault](https://serverfault.com/) instead. Just remember that they most likely (just like us) will need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Only with your screenshot it is hard to say, what went wrong. Most likely, after doing an upgrade, something went wrong. I would advice you to reinstall apache:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**Make sure to backup everything important from your Apache2-Directories, before reinstalling.**